# ngFor does not render elements into IOS browsers

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, polyfills

I'm trying to learn Angular and followed the example described [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/04/basic-crud-angular-and-spring-boot). It works fine into my desktop (macOS 10.13.3 / Safari 11.0.3; Chrome 64.0).

However, when I access it through an iphone (ios 11.2.5 / Chrome 64.0)
 -- I started it using ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --, the page does not render completely.

I modified the example and added two headers, as follows. As you can see into the image, BOF and EOF are rendered, but the div inside it aren't.

Searching, I found that I should enable polyfills. I followed examples from [here](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support). I also modified `main.ts` and included `import './polyfills.ts';`

So my question is how do I configure angular to display content on both platforms (desktop/mobile)?

**EDIT**

Seems  that the problem is related with the service that populates the `cars` variable. My component looks like:

```
export class CarListComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: Array<any>;

  constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.cars = data;
    });
  }
}
```

If, instead calling the service, I manually populate the array, the list is properly rendered...

```
export const TEMP: any[] = [
  {
    name: 'Car 1'
  }, {
    name: 'Car 2'
  }, {
    name: 'Car 3'
  }
];
```

And then

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.cars = TEMP;
  }
```

The code will work on IOS Safari/Chorme. The problem is not with the service, because if I use `console.log(data)`, it shows that it is filled with valid information. I think the problem is related to Observable...

```
<h2>BOF</h2>

<div *ngFor="let car of cars">
  {{car.name}}
</div>

<h2>EOF</h2>
```

[image]

**Versions:**

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.7
Node: 8.9.4
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.1
@angular/cli: 1.6.7
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/material: 5.2.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.7
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, and I'm ashamed...

My `getAll()` method into `car.service.ts` was pointing to "localhost"... I just changed it to an IP, and it worked....

```
  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('//10.10.10.10:8080/cars');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a change detection issue. Are you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`? If so, then you'd need to manually call `ChangeDetectorRef` `markForCheck()` after changes. Or you might try using the `async` pipe, which would forgo the need for `markForCheck()`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.cars = this.carService.getAll()
}
```

and

```
<h2>BOF</h2>

<div *ngFor="let car of cars | async">
  {{car.name}}
</div>

<h2>EOF</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks @John, but didn't worked. No, I'm not using ChangeDetectionStrategy. I changed the component to use it and it stoped to populate cars. I also tried async, with no lucky.

Comment: @BobRivers then I think your assertion that it's like an incompatibility with observables in iOS is likely correct. Here's one answer that addresses getting observables to work (in that case the issue appears to be with NgZone). https://stackoverflow.com/a/36758569/5490505 (note, I don't think this actually addresses _your_ problem) I imagine more S.O. searching in that area might work. Looking for IE solutions, rather than Safari solutions, might provide more answers & still solve the problem